# where i can find azure logs for tracking api response

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I want to view logs in azure, I mean logs that I have in the console in localhost where I can find them in web site deployed in azure? I am consuming an external API and I want to see what I send and what I received from the prod env
thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to track logs in Azure

1. Azure API Management
2. Azure Monitor

[Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor) helps you track all kinds of requests including

- View activity logs
- View resource logs
- View metrics of your API
- Set up an alert rule when your API gets unauthorized calls

[Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/rest-api-walkthrough) on the other hand helps it possible to programmatically retrieve the available default metric definitions, granularity, and metric values.

The data can be saved in a separate data store such as Azure SQL Database, Azure Cosmos DB, or Azure Data Lake. From there additional analysis can be performed as needed.

Comment: i want to be able to trace what i send to an API so I use azure monitor?

Comment: Yes, you can use Azure Monitor for all sorts of tracking.